# Merging Cells in Excel

Tags: excel

How can I merge two cells in excel using "if" condition for an example; cells A1, B1,C1... displaying same data say "ABS". Now when I type ABS in B1 it should automatically merge with A1 and display only ABS rather than ABS / ABS.
Thanx in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: I think your question is not about programming and there is not any tried code that we could help you on it, So migrate your question to [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) site, It will make more sense there ;).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you were meaning. However you can open up VBA by pressing **Alt + F11**. You should see a list of worksheet names, double click on the one that has your data and enter the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$B$1" Then
    If Range("B1").Value = Range("A1").Value And Not (Range("A1").Value = "") Then
        Range("B1").ClearContents
    End if
End If

End Sub
```

Now press **Alt + Q** to return to Excel. If you now enter the same text in cell **B1** that is currently in **A1** then the text you have just entered in cell **B1** will be deleted.

I am confused by you use of the word merge as this will simply delete text, not combine it. So if this answer isn't what you were looking for please clarify your question.

Comment: actually have to update daily attendance sheet in excel. So, what i want to know is that when i type "P" in cell A1 and again if i type "P" in cell B1, the cells A1 and B1 should merge automatically rather then manually merging the cells.

Comment: Do you mean if you type the letter p at the start of the text it merges? For example if cell **A1** says **PABC** and cell **B1** says **P123** then you want to have both deleted and cell **A1** to say **PABC123**? If not I can't understand what text it is you would like merging and it might be worth posting us a sample of the table you are using.

Comment: I tried to post the worksheet but cud not. Dont know how, my method did not work.. give me uer mail id, i will send u the work sheet